# How to use a variable as a file name in a file stream in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, filestream

I'm working on saving a list as a binary file in my game. The problem is I want to use a variable taken from an input field and use it as the name in which to save the stream. Unfortunately I can't just escape using quotes as it gives me a squiggly red line under the variable.

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Items/+"MapNameField"+.dat");
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition to the typos in your code in general: **DO NOT USE `+ "/"`**! For system paths **always** go through [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which uses the correct path separator! `File.Create(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Items", MapNameField + ".dat");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your +'s  are in the wrong spot

```
"/Items/+"MapNameField"+.dat"
```

Needs to be:

```
"/Items/"+MapNameField+".dat"
```

Or, better yet, use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) as @derHugo suggested:

```
File.Create(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Items", MapNameField + ".dat")
```

Comment: Problems caused by a typo are off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: And in addition to the typos in the code in general: **DO NOT USE `+ "/"`**! For system paths **always** go through [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which uses the correct path separator! `File.Create(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Items", MapNameField + ".dat");`

Comment: @derHugo Excellent point.  Edited that in